# Как изменить параметр в Animator c помощью кнопки интерфейса UI?

Tags: unity3d

не могу добавить на кнопку, запуск анимации меню,
есть параметр `isOpend` нужно изменить его на `false` как это сделать ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У аниматора есть метод SetBool(string, bool). Этот метод принимает соответственно имя переменной и значение, которое нужно установить.

[Документация Unity по параметрам аниматора](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/AnimationParameters.html) (с примерами изменения из кода).

Напрямую из кнопки этого не сделать т.к. OnClick в инспекторе принимает только один параметр, а значит он и не сможет вызвать нужный вам метод. Следовательно у вас есть два варианта решения:

1. Создать класс, в этом классе будет ссылка на нужный вам аниматор и публичный метод, который будет менять bool на нужное вам значение. Вызывать этот метод привычным вас способом через инспектор.
2. Изучить возможность подписки на событие кнопки OnClick из кода. В этом случае вы сможете более гибко настраивать реакцию на нажатие кнопок. Вот вам [соответствующая документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) с примером.